# Whats the best way to add cloth physics to anime style mesh hair in 2.9?

Tags: modeling, physics, eevee-render-engine

I've decided to go with cloth physics, unless someone gives me a good reason to use soft body, but I'm struggling to figure out which method is best for animation. In my research I came a crossed at least 3 methods of doing this, on bones, to the mesh itself, and at it to a separate mesh to deform the hair. This is form animation, not still images, and characters will be either falling, in water, space, fast moving, fighting, running and so on.

So my question is which is the best method, why, and how to do it. Also, what's the best way to keep it from deforming to mush and clipping.

I'm using blender 2.9 and the eevee engine.

Comment: Hmm, I might try using internal air pressure to keep it from collapsing, but have you tried changing the collision settings?

Comment: Not yet, I'm still learning about a few things.